# Adding string within a P element in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Not sure how to do this. Expected output is:

```
<p data-rating="3" class="starability-result">
```

Actual output:

```
<p is="data-rating="3"" class="starability-result">
```

Here is the code I have where 'review.rating' is the rating (1-5) returned in json.

```
const rating = document.createElement('p', `data-rating="${review.rating}"`);
rating.className = 'starability-result';
rating.innerHTML = `Rated: ${review.rating} stars`;
li.appendChild(rating);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't provide attributes as an argument to `document.createElement()`, you need to do that as a separate step.

```
const rating = document.createElement('p');
rating.className = 'starability-result';
rating.dataset.rating = review.rating; // or rating.setAttribute("data-rating", review.rating);
rating.innerHTML = `Rated: ${review.rating} stars`;
li.appendChild(rating);
```